# Steam not downloading games

Tags: steam, technical-issues

Hello I have a few games on Steam that I had downloaded, i downloaded space engineers yesterday, today I log on and need to update it. I try to update it but it get's to 98.0mb/2GB and it stops. If i press pause or try move a different game to the top of the queue it just resets back to 0mb/2GB and then gets stuck again. Why does this happen. I live in Ireland and when I tried to set it to download from the UK or Sweden in the settings that would not work either. Does anyone know how to fix this or what do I do? I did uninstall steam and reinstall steam and it still dosn't work. Heres an image.

[image: Image of download screen.]

Comment: How long have you left it for, it's possible that the game is doing something with the files mid download before it resumes

Comment: its been 5 hours, it does it for every game I have. CSGO, SPace engineers, terraria, tf2 etc.

Comment: In that case, have you tried installing something new? It could also be your hard drive space

Comment: i have 280GB/800GB free

Comment: Worth editing that in :P

Comment: Change your download region in Steam's settings. This can help sometimes.

Comment: I did that @Kaizerwolf

Comment: Did you run a checkdisk on your disk? If you have bad clusters, than this could happen.

Comment: Do you live in a country with a data cap on your Internet?

Comment: No, its Ireland :/

Comment: Do you have any other problems / impacts with your internet connection? Is it only Steam?

Comment: just steam :( @mabu

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I just did a checkdisk now 0 bad files.

Comment: I would give a try to reinstall steam client. After reinstall you can add your steam library (there where your games are stored).

Comment: @mabu just did that now and it still dosnt work.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Have a look at aiusepsi's post in this steam discussion: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864979008818608129/   It's some interesting information and explains the situation very nice.

Comment: @mabu so even though it resets to 0mb every mnute it should still work?

Comment: I know you've already had this suggest - and it's a bit of a pain - but you might try a few other locations.  I had this issue a few weeks back and tried about 6 locations, in the US, where I live.  None of them were working, for anything.  Finally I gave up and tried St. Petersburg, Russia.  Downloads worked fine from there.  (I wouldn't keep it on a long-range server, but temporarily.....if it works.) (Note: x_Vex_x's comment on the above mentioned steam thread, was the reason that I tried Russia, though I haven't seen this thread before.)

Comment: At 7MB/s I'd assume you literally broke the internet. Try capping yourself (limit download rate) or resetting (and release/renew the IP of) your router.